# Problems With Port Forwarding

Tags: internet, port-forwarding, port, modem

hope everyone is doing ok! So I have a problem with port forwarding and I cannot get it to work. I'm trying to port forward on port 25565 and I have also tried other port's like 80, 8080, 3396, 4782, and some others but nothing works. I'm doing this on Windows 10 and my firewall is disabled. My modem is a Ubee EVW32C-0N. Everyone I asked had no clue why it's not working and I know my ISP is not blocking any ports. I have tried it like this :

[image: forwarding rule 1st try]

[image: forwarding rule 2nd try]

[image: forwarding rule 3rd try]

I have also tried replacing 0.0.0.0 with my public IP.
Thank you for your attention and have a good day! :)

EDIT : I made it work somehow now but the port only opens when I run the server I cannot make it be open all the time.

Comment: 1) How did you verify that your ISP is not blocking any ports? 2) How did you check what your public IP address is? 3) Is it in fact the same address as the one shown in your modem's own connection status page?

Comment: 1)  I called them and they confirmed they are not blocking any port 2) I just went onto google and some other websites to check 3) it is I checked multiple times

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463760/is-it-possible-to-run-web-server-on-private-ip/51463925#51463925

Comment: What are you trying to port forward and how are you checking to see if it's working or not?

Comment: im just trying to port forward port 25565 for a minecraft server and im testing it with         1. https://www.canyouseeme.org/      2. https://portchecker.co/canyouseeme     3. My friend tried to join my server

Comment: To confirm, typically there should only be one entry with the local IP of your Minecraft server (so no multiple entries for port `25565` and never any entries for local IP `192.168.0.0` or `192.168.0.1`). For the local IP, `192.168.0.14` (by itself) might work, assuming that is the actual local IP of your Minecraft server.

Comment: I think you meant I should not type a port for local IP. If I don't type the port in then it gives me an error and I have to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to read the [instruction](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1373938/Ubee-Evw32c.html?page=62#manual) for your modem.

Please make sure that:

> Local IP - Defines the IP address of the local LAN device to which the
> forwarding rule applies. For example, an Xbox or PC.
>
> External IP - Designates another router's IP address on the network
> through which to forward data.

`Local IP` must be IP of device to which you want to forward ports. Ie if your PC is 192.168.0.14 that is the address which should be filled in.

`External IP` field is supposed to have your subnet's address `192.168.0.0` which will inform router to forward data though it.

Check out page 63 of the instruction:

> 6.4.3.3 Setting Up Port Forwarding for an Xbox Example

It will help you understand what different options are for.

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. https://gyazo.com/6b7a1e342f9fb3f011c75baf75281957                      thank you for the quick response thoe!

Comment: Try investigate where is the problem: [helpful tips](https://customer.cradlepoint.com/s/article/How-To-Troubleshoot-Port-Forwarding-Issues). If that does not work you will have to look info your ISP if he really does not block anything. Lot's of them profile clients, and automatically block certain ports (ie. SMTP 25). I had to specifically call them so they profiled my connection differently.

Comment: I tried the helpful tips but still no luck and I have called my ISP around 10 times by now just for port forwarding and they always said they are not blocking anything.

Comment: Is this router provided by ISP? If so you could ask them for help during configuration. Also make sure that service what you trying to access is from within network ie. from other machine. Event you could have firewall disabled on router yours target machine could have some rules that forbids incoming connection.

Comment: Yes the router is provided by the ISP but they said they cannot help me with port forwarding. My firewall is disabled on my PC and router at all times